# JQuery slidedown menu without ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, menu

Sorry this is a nube question, im just getting used to javascript.

I want to create a slidedown menu similar to the one found here:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/mega-drop-downs/index.html

The problem with this menu is that it uses ajax to call the menu content which 1) means the back/forward navigation for the user is confusing because it back/forwards through the ajax #hashtags rather than the pages the user has been on, and 2) there is a lag in loading the content for each menu item as it is called.

Does anyone know of any good jquery menu packages that have this same effect (.slidedown) without using ajax? (or can anyone suggest a way to modify this menu so that it does not use ajax).

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I copied part of their js.

```
// populates the menu according to what link was clicked, opens it if not already opened
populateMenu: function (currentLink) {
    dd.removeClass(pages);
    dd.addClass(currentLink + " open");
    dd.slideDown(speed, function () {
        // callback that runs after menu finishes sliding down
        $("nav ul li.menu>a.active").find("span").html(upArrow);
        // ajax call is below; it appends a timestamp to prevent caching, in case of dynamic content; remove if you like
        dd.load(dir + "/" + currentLink + ext + "?" + new Date().getTime(), function () {
            // callback that runs after menu finishes loading
            dd.removeClass("loading");
            addCloseLink();
        });
    });
    // change the hash according to the clicked link
    document.location.hash = currentLink;
},
```

If you change the `dd.load` call for a modify statement with jQuery like `dd.html(...)` with the content of your choice, you do not have to use ajax.

If you remove the `document.location.hash = currentLink;` line at the end of the function, it will not modify your back/forward navigation.

That would end up looking something like:

```
populateMenu: function (currentLink) {
  dd.removeClass(pages);
  dd.addClass(currentLink + " open");
  dd.slideDown(speed, function () {
    // callback that runs after menu finishes sliding down
    $("nav ul li.menu>a.active").find("span").html(upArrow);
    dd.html($('#your_source_here'));
    dd.removeClass("loading");
    addCloseLink();
  });
},
```

**Edit:**

You could also use a jQueryUI tabs with collapsible content, see [demo here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#collapsible). It would require styling but should work with maybe less work than adapting the previous code.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKqhg/1/) for a basic example. Only the styling of the tabs need to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply jaudette but im not sure i fully understand. Do you mean change it to look like this>            dd.slideDown(speed, function () {
   // callback that runs after menu finishes sliding down
   $("nav ul li.menu>a.active").find("span").html(upArrow);
   // ajax call is below; it appends a timestamp to prevent caching, in case of dynamic content; remove if you like
   dd.html(...);
  ); ?

Comment: @user1527123 Updated the answer with possible code, not tested or anything.

Comment: @user1527123 i would go to jQueryUI tabs myself. See jsFiddle in answer to get a feel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery menu introduced in version 1.9:

http://jqueryui.com/menu/